# Find non- english characters in mysql

Tags: mysql, non-english

I have a MySQL table which stores email contents as a `blob` data type. A few of the rows have non-english characters in them. Is there any ways to find only the rows which contain non-english characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
...
where some_column regexp '.*[^\\w.@].*'
```

Comment: this soluting not working in my case. because email contents also contains HTML tags ie html type eamil contents are stored. we need disregard these HTML tags in search

Comment: Modify your question to be more specific about what you seek.

Comment: i have column " details" in one table. that column stores email contents in HTML format , column data type is blob .my requirement to search and find any email content contains non -english characters ie foreign languages. the table with 51000 records. in 51000 records, i need filter only email with non -English characters. it may be 100 or greater than that . once i filter those records , i will manually identify the languages using google translator

Answer (score 0):

```
descr LIKE '%[' + CHAR(127)+ '-' +CHAR(255)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
```

Answer (score -1):

select * from TABLE where COLUMN like '%\0%';

This is working for me on MySQL 5.6 and am happy to use without even thinking how it works. Would be thankful if someone adds an explanation of how this works.

Comment: You should edit your answer to add explanation and formatting.